# First repeat value from array using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this

`$arr = array(10, 20, 50, 80, 20, 10, 30);`

I need to get first repeat value using **php** code only. Don't use **php array** functions. help me guys. 
So **ans** is - 20.

Comment: Smells like a homework!!

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Why no `array` functions?

Answer (score 6):

Try that (or just do your homework)

```
function do_your_homework($arr) {
    $seen = [];
    foreach($arr as $a) {
        if (isset($seen[$a])) return $a;
        $seen[$a] = 1;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It uses the `$seen` array to store values that are already seen (empty at first). Then for each value in the input array `$arr` it checks if the value has already been seen:

- if if was already seen, then that's the second occurence of a value, it found what it was looking for and returns the value
- otherwise it marks the value as seen by adding an entry in `$seen` array

If it goes out of the loop, that means it didn't find anything with two occurences, it returns `false` so you can test for `=== false` to know if something was found or not.

Comment: **+1** For that function name :D

Comment: very nice....lot of thanks.

Comment: Pls can you explain me How its working.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$arr = array(10, 20, 50, 80, 20, 10, 30);
$new_arr= array();

for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$arr++)
{
    if(in_array($arr[$i],$new_arr))
    {
        $dup = $arr[$i]; break; 
    }
    else
    {
        $new_arr[$i] = $arr[$i];
    }
}
```

You will get your first duplicate in $dup variable.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
<?php

$arr = array(10, 20, 50, 80, 20, 10, 30);

echo get_first_repeated($arr);

function get_first_repeated($array){
    $junk=array();
    foreach( $array as $v){
        if(in_array($v , $junk)){
            return $v;
        }
        $junk[] = $v;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `in_array` is probably an `array function`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getfirstdup()
{

$arr = (10, 20, 50, 80, 20, 10, 30);
$count = array();    

foreach ($arr as $ar) {
    if (isset($count[$ar])) return $ar;

    $count[$ar] = 1;
}

}
```

Comment: `array_flip` and `array_unique` are probably considered `array functions`.

Comment: ok thanks for pointing the requirement out. let me fix it :)